# scalamock newexpectationexception - [scala,scalamock,akka-http]

Tags: scala, akka, scalamock

I was playing with ScalaMock. I wrote a KISS version of the error of I facing when I am trying to use ScalaMock to mock an object in a test case.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MockFactory
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import akka.http.scaladsl.testkit.ScalatestRouteTest
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import org.scalatest.Matchers._

trait MetricsRegistry {
  def recordValue(myString: String): Unit
  def decatMyString(myString: String): Unit
}



class ScalaMockError01Spec extends FlatSpec with MockFactory with ScalatestRouteTest {

def actorRefFactory = system
   lazy val metricsRegistry = mock[MetricsRegistry]

  val route : Route = {
    get{
      complete("Status is OK")
    }
  }

  "MetricDirectives" should "record latency and success count for 200 response" in {
    inAnyOrder {
      (metricsRegistry.recordValue _).expects(*).twice

    }

    Get("/success") ~> route ~> check {
      status.toString() shouldBe "200 OK"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows

> Unsatisfied expectation:
>
> Expected: inAnyOrder {   inAnyOrder {
>        MetricsRegistry.recordValue(*) twice (never called - UNSATISFIED)   } }
>
> Actual:    ScalaTestFailureLocation: ScalaMockError01Spec at
>   (ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>   org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: Unsatisfied expectation:
>
> Expected: inAnyOrder {   inAnyOrder {
>        MetricsRegistry.recordValue(*) twice (never called - UNSATISFIED)   } }
>
> Actual:
>         at org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory$class.newExpectationException(AbstractMockFactory.scala:51)
>     at
>   ScalaMockError01Spec.newExpectationException(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>     at
>   ScalaMockError01Spec.newExpectationException(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.scalamock.context.MockContext$class.reportUnsatisfiedExpectation(MockContext.scala:45)
>     at
>   ScalaMockError01Spec.reportUnsatisfiedExpectation(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.scalamock.MockFactoryBase$class.verifyExpectations(MockFactoryBase.scala:108)
>     at
>   org.scalamock.MockFactoryBase$class.withExpectations(MockFactoryBase.scala:56)
>     at
>   ScalaMockError01Spec.withExpectations(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.scalamock.scalatest.AbstractMockFactory$class.withFixture(AbstractMockFactory.scala:34)
>     at ScalaMockError01Spec.withFixture(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.invokeWithFixture$1(FlatSpecLike.scala:1679)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTest$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestImpl(Engine.scala:289)  at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTest(FlatSpecLike.scala:1692)     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTest(FlatSpec.scala:1685)   at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$runTests$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:396)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:373)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:410)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine$$anonfun$traverseSubNodes$1$1.apply(Engine.scala:384)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.traverseSubNodes$1(Engine.scala:384)    at
>   org.scalatest.SuperEngine.org$scalatest$SuperEngine$$runTestsInBranch(Engine.scala:379)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runTestsImpl(Engine.scala:461)     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.runTests(FlatSpecLike.scala:1750)    at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.runTests(FlatSpec.scala:1685)  at
>   org.scalatest.Suite$class.run(Suite.scala:1147)   at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpec.org$scalatest$FlatSpecLike$$super$run(FlatSpec.scala:1685)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$$anonfun$run$1.apply(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)
>     at org.scalatest.SuperEngine.runImpl(Engine.scala:521)  at
>   org.scalatest.FlatSpecLike$class.run(FlatSpecLike.scala:1795)     at
>   ScalaMockError01Spec.org$scalatest$BeforeAndAfterAll$$super$run(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.liftedTree1$1(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:213)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfterAll$class.run(BeforeAndAfterAll.scala:210)
>     at ScalaMockError01Spec.run(ScalaMockError01Spec.scala:22)  at
>   org.scalatest.tools.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.scala:45)     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1340)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun$1.apply(Runner.scala:1334)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)  at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.doRunRunRunDaDoRunRun(Runner.scala:1334)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1011)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$$anonfun$runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter$2.apply(Runner.scala:1010)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.withClassLoaderAndDispatchReporter(Runner.scala:1500)
>     at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.runOptionallyWithPassFailReporter(Runner.scala:1010)
>     at org.scalatest.tools.Runner$.run(Runner.scala:850)    at
>   org.scalatest.tools.Runner.run(Runner.scala)  at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.runScalaTest2(ScalaTestRunner.java:138)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.testingSupport.scalaTest.ScalaTestRunner.main(ScalaTestRunner.java:28)

May I know why I am getting the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

silly me, I need to call the mocked function

> metricsRegistry.recordValue("my name is billa")